# Encryption is corrupting BMP files but not jpeg files

Tags: c#, .net, file, filestream

My decryption code is, for some strange reason, cutting off the last few bits:

[image]

Why is this happening? Have I forgotten some code, or am I making some naïve mistake?

```
private static int chunkSize = 1048576;
public void Decrypt(string Input, string passPhrase, string sender)
{
    for (long i = 0; i < fsInput.Length; i += chunkSize)
    {
        byte[] chunkData = new byte[chunkSize];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = fsInput.Read(chunkData, 0, chunkSize)) > 0)
        {
            cryptoStream.Write(chunkData, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you do a binary compare of the pre and post jpg's or just a visual one? It might be that they aren't equal either but the fault simply made a blue pixel 1% darker.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd I actually converted the file fi.bmp to fi.jpg in paint, they both look the same in the editor and all photo viewers I could think of. then I encrypted both files separately, only the jpeg can be decrypted into a valid file

Comment: Use a binary compare, not a visual comparison to test. Do you trust your eye to see the difference?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd well it turns out that the files are the same but I guess jpeg files are more immune to such problems.. can you help me with the other problem please, the files are missing a few bytes in the end of the file

Comment: You missed the final bytes. You probably didn't dispose/close/flush the streams correctly

Comment: JPEG is much more bit sensitive than BMP. Change one bit in JPEG and it can totally screw things up.

Comment: **Show your encryption and decryption code**. Don't make us guess.

Comment: @JanDoggen the error is in the code above and has been solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was missing `cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();` from the decrypt method

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
                    if (bytesRead != chunkSize)
                    {
                        for (int x = bytesRead - 1; x < chunkSize; x++)
                        {
                            chunkData[x] = 0;
                        }
                    }
```

Assume you have read 5 bytes, that is the indices 0 through 4, then `x=5-1=4`, so the last byte you have read will be overwritten by a zero byte.

Furthermore you do not write out the complete last block, only the first `bytesRead` many bytes:

```
                    cryptoStream.Write(chunkData, 0, bytesRead);
```

Your somewhat chaotic read functionality assures that the last block will not even be read partially, so that masks the error. To repair your code, write out a complete block every time. Also throw away the file read logic. You have two loops that don't mix together and the inner is completely sufficient. Furthermore, all of it will crash (in the sense of silently dropping data), if `fsInput.Read` reads less than the requested bytes, even though you are not yet at the end of the file. You should check whether the API guarantees that behaviour.

Comment: but then why does the jpeg remain valid? This obviously won't just affect bmp files..

Comment: If the size of the jpeg file is not by chance a multiple of the block size (then your bug will not occur), please do a byte by byte comparison of the decrypted file with the original. (@user3549636)

Comment: Not all file formats are equal against corruption, so yes it could corrupt some and not others depending on the importance of the data there (optional header / footer data, data that when corrupted just changes the color of a pixel vs makes the file unreadable etc etc). As it was suggested check that the files that work ARE actually the same (not just visually, do a byte per byte compare) before encryption, and after encrypting and decrypting, i'm certain you'll find they're not and you're just "Lucky" they happen to still work

Comment: @RonanThibaudau I'll try with a .txt file to be sure.. just a sec

Comment: @RonanThibaudau Check the edit^^ any Idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Most likely exactly like @Perseids answer suggested, did you try?

Comment: @user3549636: You mean, like writing `x=bytesRead` instead of `x=bytesRead - 1`? There are yet more problems with your code, though. I believe you do not actually chop of the extra bytes you added to fill the last block.

Comment: @Perseids still chops the last block

Comment: @user3549636, see the edit. Btw. Stackoverflow is not your personal debugging service. For your next question, please do some more thorough debugging up front and reduce your question to a minimum working (or failing in this case) example.

Comment: @Perseids if I were to replace bytesRead with chunkSize a 5kb file would end up being 1 mb large